Does Bell’s theorem rule out changing hidden variables?
In the EPR experiment, it is said that there are predictions that are made if there are hidden variables determined by something locally in each particle that results in a correlation in entanglement. And that these predictions don’t agree with the predictions in QM.
Do these same predictions apply even if the spin changes multiple times during its travel before reaching a detector? Or does it only apply if this property is constant once it’s emitted from the source?

Bell's theorem applies to any classical random variable.  The source of the randomness (including random evolution while a particle is traveling) does not affect the result.

Got it. Do you mind explaining how other proposed theories solve that then? @WillO Like Bohmian mechanics etc. Does it involve communication among the particles during travel?

@Alejandro Good question because it involves variable alterations, such as oscillation. When examining the correlation between two photons’ variables, factors like speed, direction, frequency, and polarization naturally come to mind. While the bell test focuses on polarization, it overlooks potential alterations in route. Introducing an alternating variable yields notably different outcomes. Each photon possesses energy that oscillates in proportion to its frequency, introducing a linear dependency that aligns mathematically with quantum mechanics, reflected in cos^2(theta) results.

@BillAlsept But even if it was oscillating, wouldn’t the expected statistical results still differ from the ones predicted in QM? If not, why not?

@Alejandro no, when you add the alternating variable (something any real particle would have) to the math it matches QM predictions of cos2theta.

Alejandro:  What @BillAlsept is telling you is absolutely wrong.  He has a long history of giving wrong answers to questions like this, and failing to digest the many comments pointing out his errors.  You can always trust Andrew Steane, who I see has posted an answer.

@Alejandro, it's clear that WillO's only contribution lies in hurling insults, especially when discussing real, tangible subjects like the one you've raised. He seems more inclined to cling to tired, dead-end ideas rather than ever entertaining a spark of original thought. I can say this because he nor Andrew answered your question relating to changing variables. Probably because they didn't understand it. If they did they would realize that limits would not apply when a linear dependent variable was added to the mix. Experimental results would reveal a cos2theta matching.

I just don’t understand how it would result in a violation of Bell inequalities sorry @BillAlsept unless you can explain with more detail

@Alejandro there are no inequalities when you consider all the variables. An oscillating (or changing) variable is important. When you PERFECTLY correlate two particles in every possible physical way (which would include a rotating or oscillating property) then it's easily possible to match the math of QM. You can even correlate two real macro size particles to easily demonstrate this in reality. On the other hand QM only offers math which happens to match a real and PERFECTLY correlated pair of particles, that don't leave out important linear dependent variables like oscillation.

This is best answered by using the idea of causality in special relativity. At each event there is a region of spacetime, called the backwards light cone, which contains all previous events that could possibly send an influence to that event. The Bell inequality applies to events not happening at the same place and which do not permit communication from one to the other at speeds less than or equal to light speed. Such events are said to be spacelike-separated. Bell's mathematical formulation considers a set of correlations between observations at the two events. To observe such correlations in practice one has to imagine the scenario is repeated many times with the same setup. The argument then shows there is a limit on the correlations if they are brought about by communication of classical information from a common event in the past light cones. The classical information can be changing with time as long as the probability distribution describing the possible observations at any event A does not depend on variables (hidden or otherwise) which can be influenced by events spacelike-separated from A. In other words, within the restriction of

describing physical situations using probability distributions (not wavefunctions)

ordinary limits on communication (as implied by special relativity)


one infers a restriction on a set of correlations. Quantum theory predicts the restriction can be broken, and observations agree with quantum theory.
Thus, Bell's argument does cover dynamic hidden variables, not just static ones. It's a long time since I read the paper and I don't recall him directly pointing this out in the text, but I think what I have written here is contained implicitly in the beautiful argument he discovered.

Okay thank you. Do you know other proposed theories are supposed to explain these correlations then? Like Bohmian mechanics etc

The textbook by Peres is good on this. Bohmian mechanics allows non-Lorentz-covariant features in the pilot wave.

Does that involve communication between the particles?

@Alejandro Bohmian mechanics requires a guide wave that is formed at the time of emission and goes everywhere instantaneously and 'feels' out the environment in advance to guide the particle and the pilot wave adapts instantaneously to any change in the environment, so in a sense the pilot wave communicates with itself without being limited to the speed of light and is very non local.  Bohmian mechanics does not get round the non locality issue. Some descriptions of the pilot wave describe it as going forward and backward in time.

In my more detailed answer to a related question I mention how the correlations have to match the outcome of the equation $\sin^2(A-B)$ where A is the alignment of Alice's analyser and B is the alignment of Bob's analyser, in order to match the predictions of Quantum Mechanics.
Notice that the quantum prediction $\sin^2(A-B)$ does not include a variable for the polarisation of the incoming photon quantum so its polarisation is not important other than its assumed to be random. Any theory that is local and uses hidden variables only has the information about the angle of the incoming photon and the angle of the local analyser, so it cannot reproduce the $\sin^2(A-B)$ correlation, as it does not know both A and B. It does not matter if the incoming photon has a constant polarisation all along its route or if it is constantly changing. Either way it does not help determine $\sin^2(A-B)$.
In my other answer, I set up a game and a device that only uses local information and manage to produce the correct correlations when the analysers have the same orientation, the opposite orientation and when they are 45 degrees apart, but it fails, (as any local theory will always fail) at the angles in between.
Clarification note: In the other answer I used the $\cos^2(A-B)$ correlation equation, because I was using the example that the entangled photons were orientated the same way while in this answer I used the $\sin^2(A-B)$ equation which is the most often used and assumes the entangled photons are orientated at 90 degrees to each other. The orientations of entangled photons to each, depends on the method used to prepare them.

Bell's theorem assumes
(1) that at the time of measurement, the measured quantities are described by stochastic variables: single numbers with probabilities,
(2) that the measurement devices or particles don't somehow have information about what measurement settings will be chosen in advance and
(3) that any communication between the systems being measured happens locally.
Given these constraints the correlations between the measured quantities satisfy the Bell inequalities. Quantum theory doesn't satisfy the Bell inequalities.

Your (1) is not an assumption of Bell. Your (2) is incorrect as well. The assumption is that the particles being measured don’t have advance information about how they to be measured. More specifically, that the setting for one measurement device does not influence the outcome of the other.

On assumption 2 if either the measurement devices or the particles have information about what would be measured in advance then they might in principle reproduce the Bell correlations locally, although there is no existing theories with those properties.

As for assumption 1, Bell does assume that. See Chapter 13 of "Speakable and Unspeakable in Quantum Mechanics" where he talks about hidden variables producing a probability distribution for the variables we actually measure, which are supposed to have single values. So the quantities we measure are stochastic variables.

Regarding your assumption 2: upon re-reading, we’re saying the same thing. Regarding 1: Bell specifically says the hidden variables could take any form, and the even be functions or sets.

Just to add to Andrew’s correct answer: The EPR idea (pre-Bell) needs to be kept in mind at all times as well. They pointed out that entanglement should lead to perfect correlations when identical observations are performed.
So… if one of the particles is changing mid-flight, the other one must be changing the same way. And… it doesn’t matter when they are detected relative to each other either. So how could they really be changing mid flight and still be perfectly correlated?
The point is: Both the EPR perfect correlations AND the Bell Inequality violations must be simultaneously considered with any alternative hypothesis.
