Time required to reach Black Hole's Event Horizon from outsider perspective?
Let's imagine a pair of particles that is entangled. One (call it $P_1$) is released and then falls to a black hole from a distant $x_0$, (for example $x_0=5r_s$) and velocity $v_0(=1/2c)$, while the other particle ($P_2$) is stationary.
It is more likely for $P_1$ to reach the event horizon (EH) in a finite time ($P_1$ cannot see the end of the universe) (although $P_2$ "see" $P_1$ takes infinite time to reach EH).
Hypothesize that the $P_1$ somehow can change its states when reaching EH, and thus we can measure it by measuring the state of $P_2$ (entangled) without actually "seeing" it enter the black hole.
I know it is not how quantum entanglement works, but just let's imagine this is the case.
So, my question is how long is required for $P_1$ to reach EH from the $P_2$'s clock perspective?
P/s: useful link for entering black holes from the falling observer perspective.

Quantum particles obey the uncertainty principle, so the state cannot change exactly at the horizon. Thus your measurement can happen any time from the first second to eternity. Your question is not well defined.

Can you clarify what you mean by the sentence "It is more likely to P1 to reach the event horizon (EH) in a finite time from its perspective."? What is the the "it" you refer to and what in comparison to what is 'it' more likely?

What is the purpose  of the 'quantum entanglement'. Is it just a means to transmit the information of the arrival time of P1 instantaneously to P2 so we can ignore the time for signal propagation?

@KDP First question: sorry, my sentence is unclear. You can have a look at the given link, my assumption is based on that thread, which is that $P_1$ cannot see the end of the universe, and reach the EH in finite time compared to $P_2$'s clock.
Second question (@safesphere for your confusion as well): yes, the real 'quantum entanglement' has nothing to do with my question, it is just the method that somehow transmits the information when $P_1$ reaches EH to $P_2$ without signal propagation.
I am just an amateur who wants to understand the concept with intuitive answers.

Measuring or manipulating one particle in an entangled pair doesn't change the other so your thought experiment proceeds from false and unclear assumptions https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/811135/all-the-logically-possible-ways-to-get-around-bell-type-inequalities/811275#811275

Let's avoid the distraction of bringing quantum entanglement into the argument and rephrase the question in terms of where the falling observer is 'now' according to the outside observer, which I suspect is what you are getting at with your question.

in the above animation, the rotating dark blue line is the Schwrszchild line of simultaneity which is effectively 'now for the outside observer. The light blue line is the world line of a photon. Everything is constrained to remain on the line of simultaneity as the universe evolves. Nothing can get off it. Even the photon has to stay on it. This line of simultaneity arrives at the event horizon after infinite coordinate time. Even if the proper time measured by the infalling observer is just 10 minutes, by the time she arrives at the event horizon, the Sun will have become a red giant, the Andromeda galaxy will have collided with our galaxy, the stars will have burnt up all their fuel and gone out. the universe would have gone dark except maybe for some bright spots due to black holes ending their lives in a last final burst of intense Hawking radiation. The infalling observer does not see any of this, because she only sees her light from her past light cone as can be seen by tracing the photon world line back to its source.
It should be clear from the above that everything takes infinite time to fall to the horizon, regardless of initial height or velocity. A more formal mathematical demonstration can be obtained by analysing the Schwarzschild metric.
If we set $ d \Omega$ to zero we obtain the purely radial form of the metric:
$$dS^2 = (1-r_s/r)c^2 dt^2 - 1/(1-r_s/r) dr^2$$
where $r_s = 2GM/(c^2)$ is the Schwarzschild radius and $r$ is the radial coordinate of the test particle.  This metric can be modified to take the location of the external observer ($r_o$) into account:
$$dS^2 = \frac{(1-r_s/r)}{(1-r_s/r_o)}c^2 dt^2 -  \frac{(1-r_s/r_o)}{(1-r_s/r)} dr^2$$
For a radially infalling photon, the proper time is zero so we can set $dS=0$ so:
$$0 = \frac{(1-r_s/r)}{(1-r_s/r_o)}c^2 dt^2 -  \frac{(1-r_s/r_o)}{(1-r_s/r)}dr^2$$
$$  dt = \frac{1}{c} \left(\frac{(1-r_s/r_o)}{(1-r_s/r)} \right) \ dr$$
For a photon falling from $r_p =r_1$ to $r_p =r_2$ we can carry out the definite integral of the above equation with respect to r using those limits:
$$\Delta t = \frac{(1-r_s/r_o)}{c}\int_{r_2}^{r_1}  \left(\frac{1}{(1-r_s/r)} \right) \ dr $$
$$\Delta t= (\Delta r +r_s (\log(r_1-r_s)-\log(r_2-r_s))) \ \times (1-r_s/r_o)/c$$
For $r_2=r_s$ we get $-\log(0) = \infty$ so $\Delta t = \infty$ for any initial location of the ingoing photon outside the event horizon ($r_1 >r_s$) and for any outside observer ($r_o >r_s$).
There is more information from Mathpages for particles with mass falling from a given height or at an initial velocity at infinity here and here.

It might also be worth noting that a real particle with nonzero energy falling into a black hole will cause the hole's event horizon to grow. So the situation isn't quite the same as an idealized test particle falling into a static black hole, and the real particle will cross the event horizon in finite time as measured by a distant observer. It might be a very very long time for a small particle though.

@EricSmith: let's say a person falls into black hole, so what is the magnitude of "finite time"? years, light years, or billions of light years?

@NhatNguyen If you use the equation from Mathpages you can set the initial height the object falls from and destination. If you select a destination that is very close to the event horizon rather than exactly at the event horizon, you can have very short falling times of the order of seconds or minutes. Most of the 'slow down' happens in the final few mm of the approach to the EH. Results will vary with the mass of the falling object and the mass of the Black Hole and the initial height and how close to the EH you decide is close enough.
